# Showing a Captcha popup after failed login

Tags: asp.net, popup, captcha

I have created two asp.net pages, if x times the login fails, I want to call the captcha page (second page) in a popup window. How do I automatically call the second page as a popup window in the first page without using a hyperlink button?

Are there any tutorials?

Comment: By the way, why would you show the Captcha in a popup window? What do you do if someone just closes it? Or by popup window, do you mean modal dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it's kind of weird that your question is significantly longer than your text.

Regardless, what you want is JavaScript:

```
window.open('foo.aspx', ...);
```

You can find more info here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: thanx for ur response.
In my home page there is a login button.if a user fail for x times it should display a popup window in Home page itself.

Comment: Yes; then you don't understand the definition of a 'popup' window. You want a modal dialog, jQuery can do this easily for you (or one of the plugins). But I don't think it's a good model, particularly. I'll let you research the best option yourself. Goodluck.